# How to use stats aggregation to compute stats over string field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document like this:

```
"_source": {  
   "@fields": {
      "category": "card",
      "content": "code",
      "time": "2014-10-22T20:17:58",
      "score": "278579"
}
```

My stats aggregation statement is:

```
"aggs": {
    "score_stats": {
         "stats": {"field": "score"}
    }
}
```

and elasticsearch throw exception

> ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData

My question is how can I use stats aggregation to get statistical result about score field which is a string type

Comment: You can't it has to be a numeric type, hence the error message.

Comment: I know field must be a numeric type, and can I use script to convert string to numeric?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, using mapping config to force score field is long type.

{

"score": {"type": "long"}

}